# Is there a way to force Steamlink to work on a Raspi Zero?

Tags: pi-zero-w, software-compatibility

I am trying to run SteamLink on my zero and I know performance will probably suck but I wanted to give it a shot. I know it says it isn't supported and when I try to start I get

`You need to run on a Raspberry Pi 3 or newer - aborting.`

I tried to set `disable_overscan=1`

but I still get the same response. Is it possible to have steamlink ingnore this?